# How to fill in text fields and checkbox using jQuery and json response?

Tags: jquery, json

Here is the code I have so far.

```
   <html>
   <head>
      <title>jQuery</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#driver").click(function(event){
                var name = $("#name").val();
                $("#stage").load('result.cfm', {"name":name} );
                //$("#test").val(name);     
            });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Enter your name and click on the button:</p>
      <input type = "input" id = "name" size = "40" /><br />
      <div id = "stage" style = "background-color:ccc;">
         STAGE
      </div>
        Results
        <input type = "button" id = "driver" value = "Show Result" />
        <br><br><br>
        Name:
        <input type = "input" id = "fullname" size = "40" /><br />
        Age:
        <input type = "input" id = "age" size = "6" /><br />
        Sex:<br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="m"> Male <br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="f"> female <br>
   </body>
</html>

<!---
Result.cfm example returned.

{
"name": "Zara Ali",
"age" : "67",
"sex": "female"
}
```

--->

Comment: Nathan, you should add actual content in your question, describing in short what you did, and what did not work for you, so people can pinpoint the problem and help you out. Dumping a block of code isn't going to help you much.

Comment: tried several things and i got the error Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 so I removed the parse since several pages said that was due to the object is already parsed. -  var obj1 = $.ajax('result.cfm' );  alert(obj1.name);   $("#fullname").val(obj1.name);

Comment: by "fill in" you mean pre-populate?